# How to see public datasets?

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset

I'm trying to view the GitHub public dataset, following instructions on the GitHub website.  The instructions there say to "add the project name githubarchive, but when on the BigQuery site I see no way to add projects.  I'm sure I'm just not signed up properly or some such thing, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 2):

Goto

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/

and setup a new project using the default name given (do not use githubarchive)

After refresh, you are forwarded into this new project, and on the left side you will see the public projects:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll first want to [sign up for Google BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/getting-started) if you haven't already.

Then, take a look at the [BigQuery Browser Tool Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/hello_bigquery_gui), which will walk you through the process of using the Web interface to run queries on public BigQuery datasets.

Note that each developer project receives a free quota of 100Gb of query processing per month. BigQuery's `publicdata:samples` table also includes a slice of the full GitHub archive project data, which is a smaller dataset.