# How to search for public datasets on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, dataset, public

Is there a way to search for public datasets on BigQuery?

Related question about viewing datasets listed by default [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461619/how-to-see-public-datasets).

There is no way to search for public datasets which are not listed in the BQ GUI under 'bigquery-public-data' as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14969215.

There is an older Reddit post listing many of the ones listed in the GUI [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/wiki/datasets).

There seems to be a separate list under fh-bigquery as seen here for a [freebase dataset](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:freebase20140119.triples). What is this fh-bigquery designation?

The Reddit page links to the Marketplace search for datasets [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?filter=solution-type:dataset).

The empty Marketplace search links to "Suggest a new solution on our Idea forum" where I have posted a general search feature. There are already two search boxes for public datasets, one in the BQ GUI and the other in the Marketplace search.

Someone even wrote a [script](https://www.the-swamp.info/blog/bigquery-public-datasets-metadata/) to create a BQ table of public dataset metadata, but again it only includes those listed by Google.

Why is there no way to find the work that the public has uploaded? Please upvote the Idea on the Marketplace to '[Allow search for BigQuery public datasets](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/599443-marketplace/suggestions/37036810-allow-search-for-bigquery-public-datasets)'.